# Webdriver - Check for exceptions in log files

Tags: selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I have one requirement as follows
- When my @Test method executes, check the log files. 
- If there any exception in log files, fail the test case. Else pass the test case

Currently, I have done following implementation
- Clearing the log files (3-4 log files) in @Beforetest code
- Checking exceptions in all log files in @AfterTestCode

But issue is that, when any @Test method pass/fail, control marks that test case execution status as PASS/FAIL and after this althoug there is any exception in my log file, my TC passes.

So can you please suggest me if any workarounds possible for that.

Vishal

Answer (score 1):

Checking exception in the @AfterMethod will not help because it checks the result of the @Test method.

For example :

```
@Test
Public void testCase(){
}

@AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result){
}
```

In the above sample result is for the @test method class result. If test case is passing it will understand pass in @AfterMethod as well.

Workaround:

1. Either check in your @Test method and based on that your AfterMethod will work fine considering the fact that @AfterMethod will execute after every test method class.
2. Create a @AfterClass Method which will check on all test cases whether they are passed or not at the end of the class.